# Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

It keeps saying class not found but i seem to see no errors in any Java class. Is it because of something wrong in the manifest file or Java Build paths? Please help. And why is asking a question so hard. It keeps saying give more details and stuff.

This is the logcat

```
04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-21 04:41:21.709: **E/AndroidRuntime(1179): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.work.pets.data.PetProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.work.pets.data.PetProvider**

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4563)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.work.pets.data.PetProvider

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4548)

04-21 04:41:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     ... 12 more

04-21 04:41:21.713: W/ActivityManager(337):   Force finishing activity com.work.pets/.Main
```

This is the complete code of Provider Class

```
package data;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import data.PetContract.PetEntry;

public class PetProvider extends ContentProvider{

private static final int PETS=100;

private static final int PET_ID=101;

public static final String LOG_TAG = PetProvider.class.getSimpleName();

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher=new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static{

sUriMatcher.addURI(PetContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, PetContract.PATH_PETS, PETS);

sUriMatcher.addURI(PetContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, PetContract.PATH_PETS + "/#", PET_ID);
}

private PetDbHelper nDbHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

nDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(getContext());

return true;

}

@Override

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

SQLiteDatabase database = nDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor;

int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

switch(match){

case PETS:cursor = database.query(PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection,
selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

break;

case PET_ID:

selection = PetEntry._ID + "=?";

selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };

cursor = database.query(PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection,
selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

break;

default:

throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI" + uri);

}

return cursor;

}
@Override

public String getType(Uri uri) {

return null;

}
@Override

public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {

final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

switch(match){

case PETS:

return insertPet(uri,contentvalues);

default:

throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported for " + uri);

}   

}
private Uri insertPet(Uri uri,ContentValues values){

SQLiteDatabase database = nDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

long id = database.insert(PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

if (id == -1) {

Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to insert row for " + uri);

return null;

}

return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);

}

@Override

public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

return 0;

}

@Override

public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

return 0;

}

}
```

This is the Provider part of Manifest File:-

```
<provider android:name=".data.PetProvider"

android:authorities="com.work.pets"

android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: Can you try in debug mode? If you are in this mode you can reach the solution step by step. Can you check petprovider class  accessibility and package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package is wrong. The code doesn't lie... This doesn't exist.

```
com.work.pets.data.PetProvider
```

`data.PetProvider` does...

Fix `package data;` to use your application's package

Comment: Need more clarification.
I had other classes like PetContract and PetDbHelper in the same 'package data' and they were working but as soon as I created this new PetProvider class in stopped working.

Comment: Clarify what? `com.work.pets` is the package name of the app. When you put `.data` in the manifest, it replaced that first dot with the application package, which isn't where your provider class exists. I didn't say anything about your other code